# Node js Keeps redirecting - Middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, firebase

I am trying to write a middleware using node js and express. If user is not authenticated it will redirect him to login page.

That's working, but once redirected to login page, it keeps redirecting to login page again and again.

```
app.get('/profile',function(req,res){
   if (isAuthenticated()) {
       res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/site/profile.html'));
   }else{
       console.log('not authenticated user at profile');
       res.redirect('/login');
   }
});
```

For login

```
app.get('/login',function(req,res){
   if (isAuthenticated()) {
       res.redirect('/profile');
   }else{
       res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/login.html'));
   }

});
```

EDIT:

Console(loop):  not authenticated user at profile

Firebase method for authentication

```
function isAuthenticated(){
   var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
   console.log(user);
   if(user && user !== null){
       return true;
   }else{
       return false;
   }
}
```

It is returning null

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here, must be somewhere else.

Comment: Please see the edit

Comment: Why do you use a redirect at all? You could hook up your login-page as middle ware and always display it with an  `401` status code if no authentication informations are send with the request.

Comment: Where does `isAuthenticated` run? If it runs in your express/node process, then `firebase.auth().currentUser` won't be the user that is accessing your middleware from the browser. You will need to pass the user's token to the server from your client code and verify it there: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use a redirect, but write an `authenticationRequired` middleware. This middleware would either send a `401` status code and display the login page, or pass the the request forward to the next callback.

```
function authenticationRequired(req, res, next) {
   if( isAuthenticated() ) {
       next()
   } else {
       res.status(401).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'login.html'));
   } 
}


// register the middleware for only one route
app.get('/profile', authenticationRequired, function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'site/profile.html'));
});

// or register the middleware for all routes that follow 
app.use(authenticationRequired)

app.get('/profile', function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/site/profile.html'));
});
```

This way you would not need to manually keep track of the url the user tried to open in the first case and after login the user will stay on the correct url.

Beside that you would use the correct status codes, instead of the `302` which tells the browser that the resource is temporary at another places you send the `401` which tells the browser that an authentication is required to display the requested resource.

Comment: Hey thanks for answer! I have implemented the same as you said, but still reloading after every 1-2 seconds. here is the code i have implemented. [PasteBin Link](https://pastebin.com/mFp8ZuXy)

Comment: This indicates that you have some other code that does reloading, do you have a html tag that does a refresh or js code? Because the serverside code you show would not have such an effect.

Comment: Oh Yes! i am using firebase onAuthStateChanged function. to redirect user if he is logged. I have commented one line that was redirecting. Here see the [code](https://pastebin.com/GngKAJa9) . But i am new to this thing. I am curious if **authStateIsChanged** to login, will it redirect user to profile? Because i have commented that line.

Comment: No! after authStateChanged to loggedIn it is not redirecting to profile page. Note: firebase code is written in Vanilla JS. @t.niese

Comment: @NomanAli this a different question, and not really related to node and express, so you should create a new question and include a link to this one if you need further help.

Comment: @NomanAli some additional notes it should be `path.join(__dirname, 'login.html')` and not `path.join(__dirname + '/login.html')` the purpose of `join` is to replace the `+` concatination, for your `app.get('/login', authenticationRequired ,function(req,res){` the `authenticationRequired` does not make sense, because the login page should be reachable without authentication.

Comment: Thanks Sir, here is new question i have created [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45158886/nodejs-and-firebase-redirect-after-login-currentuser-returns-null)