# NodeJS and Firebase Redirect After Login - currentUser returns Null

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to embed my JS Firebase app with nodejs. As I am new with Nodejs. (Not Using Admin SDK)

After loggedIN `onAuthStateChanged()` is returning null in server.js, but in app.js (Where login code is written) is printing the user details.

Here is reference to related previous problem: [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144678/node-js-keeps-redirecting-middleware/45145045?noredirect=1#comment77285737_45145045)

App.js code (That is printing user fine)

```
 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
   if (firebaseUser) {
          currentUserID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
          localStorage.setItem("currentUserID", currentUserID);
          console.log(currentUserID);
    }else{
          $('.signupform').show("slide");
          $('.signupform2').hide("slide");
          $('.loginform').show();
    }
  });
```

Server.js Code (Printing Null in console)

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
    console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser);
    console.log(firebaseUser);

    if (firebaseUser) {
        signed = true;

    }else{
        signed = false;
    }
  });
```

I am trying to implement isAuthenticated method mentioned in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144678/node-js-keeps-redirecting-middleware/45145045?noredirect=1#comment77285737_45145045)

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you using client side Firebase SDK on NodeJS? Because authentication states won't automatically work across browser and the app server.

Comment: Yes i am using client side SDK on Node Server. What should i do?